# the difference between $_REQUEST and $_POST

Tags: php, backend

I'm learning PHP and I came across the Superglobal variable $_REQUEST so I want to know what is the difference between $_POST and $_REQUEST ?

Answer (score 2):

`$_REQUEST` includes all variables from both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.